# I have problem in card I want the card deck to show horizontally but it is showing vertically

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, card

I need card deck horizontally. If I https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU7lV.jpg include stylesheets then navbar changes.

Comment: Please add more details, working code, and more info on the desired effect.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update you answer to include code snippets because your question will start to get down voted for having your code as an image.